# android: After closing my app, in Application Management, still showing Force Close

Tags: android, forceclose

I can start my app and close later. But after closing, if I go to Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applicaitons and select my app, the Force Close button is still active which means my app is running behind the scenes. Why is this...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you close your application, the process of it is still active and will be active while/if system will not kill it in the future. So in Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applicaitons you can by force kill process of your application.
This is feature of Android OS.

Comment: Sorry, I think some words are missing from your answer that's why I am unable to understand your reply. Can you elaborate again please...???

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: Sorry for my English.
Did you get answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to close your application. It still show you Force Close button but it's closes all your activity.

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```